# Bigcommerce API total cart calculation, payment

Tags: cart, bigcommerce

I am very unhappy i can not find a work around to process these two calls.

I would like to call the API with a json with all the data so that i can get a total cost of the cart. 
Also i would like to call the API so that it will process a payment for an order created.

Is there any way any of this sounds possible using any trick /hack / workaround?

Comment: This is pretty unclear, are you trying to submit the data from the cart page? or pull the data through the API from an order that was submitted into the store? Provide some more context and detail if possible.

Comment: The idea was to get the price for some products, shipment cost and taxes. The only to do this seems to be generating an order and deleteing him after we get the data.